# Javascript: suppress "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave" popup on onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, ajax, onbeforeunload

When a user leaves a page, I need to ask him if he wants to perform a particular action before leaving.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = askConfirm;
});

function askConfirm() {
    var addFriend = confirm("Would you like to ping?");
    if (addFriend) {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example.com?ping=1234",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Depending on the value of that last `return` statement (`""`, `null`, `true`, `false`, or not having a `return` statement at all) I can have one of two situations:

1) The user gets the "Would you like to ping?" confirmation (good), the ping is sent (good), and *the user is presented with a "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave" popup (BAD)*.

-or-

2) The user gets the "Would you like to ping?" confirmation (good), *the ping is **not** sent (BAD)*, and the user is **not** presented with a "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave" popup (good).

**How can I have the AJAX ping sent, yet suppress the "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave" popup?**

**Edit:** As ridiculous as it sounds, the "work around" that I found for this issue is to `alert()` after the `xmlhttp.send()` statement. The only clean way to do that is to alert the user that his ping has been sent. If future StackOverflowers find a better solution, I would love to know.

Thanks.

Comment: return `true` instead of a `null`?

Comment: @MarcB, I think that's scenario 2 in the question. Maybe the ping is "optimized away"?

Comment: @bzim: You might be right about "optimized away". Can I make something "depend" upon it?

Comment: @dotancohen, use the nickname autocompletion when replying to comments. :)

Comment: @bzlm: When I press tab the `Add Comment` button gets focus, I then have to Shift-tab back. I might as well just type out the whole thing. Are notifications only sent if one uses autocompletion? Can one autocomplete and keep focus on the textarea?

Comment: @dotancohen, the only difference autocompletion makes is it helps you spell my name right. :) The button isn't supposed to get focus when you press tab; you should file a bug on meta.

Comment: Just a note - if you don't need this confirmation message then you should use `unload` event rather than `beforeunload` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well instead of doing it before you leave, I did it onunload and here is what I got to work in FF and IE (besides chrome, that's all I got): http://jsfiddle.net/rmpLm/9/.

perhaps you can get it to work on chrome, but if you cant, maybe you could make it so that if you hit ok, it takes you to a page where you send it. hope it helps : )

EDIT: maybe you should consider making it so it does it onload

Comment: That you Aidan! You are right, moving to onunload does solve the issue for Firefox. I cannot test in IE right now (no Windows machine) but thank you for the warning. I did select Gilly's answer for the bounty as he does attack the root of the issue, but I selected your answer as the Accepted Answer. I see that you are in need of some karma at the moment so keep posting and I'll stalk around to upvote your answers in cases where I am competent to judge them! Welcome to SO!

Comment: @dotancohen and thank you so much. I don't really care that I did't get the bounty (though it'd be nice). at least I can comment now. which will help when answering. I have 58 rep points as of now so again, the bounty doesn't really matter anymore PS: I spent a lot of time working on that

Comment: Yes, I went through your four posts and ensured that they got the recognition that they deserved! Thanks for you help Aidan!

Answer (score 9):

You can make your Ajax request synchronous.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example.com?ping=1234", false); // use false here 
xmlhttp.send();
```

It might cause a slight delay if your server is slow, but it should solve the problem of the ping not being sent.

Comment: That would be an SJAX request ;)

Comment: Thank you Gilly, this does look like the root of the issue. I can confirm that the SJAX :) method does in fact send the ping under all conditions that I test under. Thanks!